# Git pull origin [branch name] vs git checkout -t origin/[branch name]

Tags: git

I do jobs in local server and push them to the branch. after that, I would like to pull the branch from remote repository to webserver. When I would like to bring the jobs updated on the branch into the web server, which command on the following is correct?

```
git pull origin [branch name]
```

vs.

```
git checkout -t origin/[branch name]
```

The job I've done on branch is now totally different with the main one. I do not want any merge branch to main so now the job on branch is like other project, nothing to do with the original project on the main. let me call the jobs I've done on the branch 'B project'. I would like to manage B project only on the branch and original one still on main.

Is that a good idea? Or is there a better way for this plan?

Comment: I dont fully understand the question to be honest but in general,
checkout is to switch branches and pull is to get new data on the current branch you are on.

If branch B is your main branch now, maybe merge them and make A branch synced with B? if you want a backup of A you can also make a new branch from A for it

Answer (score 1):

You could use separate branches for each feature. I personally use a hierarchy similar to below.

```
/
|---features
    |--- A
    |--- B
```

That would result in `/features/A` and `/features/B` branches respectively. That way you could work on your features on separate branches and use main branch as stable version of your application.

**After your last edit, I would definitely recommend the solution below.**

Or a better solution for entirely different jobs, you could use [git-worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) command.

```sh
git worktree add [-b <new-branch>] <path> [<the branch/tree you want to base this worktree>]
```

This is the best I could from what I've understand from your question.

Comment: that's a good plan I think. thanks for that. when I pull branch features/A or features/B into webserver, which command do I have to use? git pull origin features/A... something like this, right? not 'git checkout -t origin/features/A. A tutorial suguest to do 'git checkout -t origin/features/A'

Comment: If we consider that your branches are already on remote and you have only one remote (that way you could omit origin in your command). You could simply clone the repository and use `git checkout features/A`

Comment: after your last edit, Can you show me example to make me understood? let's say new branch is "features/A" then what is the branch/tree ? ..what is <path>? sorry I am new to git/github

Comment: But with my second recommendation, after you clone your repository. Use the git-worktree to use your "jobs" on different folders. That way you don't have to fiddle with merges, rebases etc

Comment: features/A is just a string, you could also say "featureA". You can use multiple nested branch names. <path> in my example is a directory in your root directory. For example if your work is on `~/myrepo`. You can direct (<path>) your worktree to `~/myrepo/featureA`

Comment: If my solution helped you, could you accept it as answer?

Comment: haha I did already. don't you see the number. thanks a lot

Comment: You should mark it as answered not upvote :) [check out here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/705141)

Answer (score 1):

For my understanding, you have a main project and a different project which is based on the main, while being significantly different.

If that's the case, I would have different repositories for the two, so to keep them more maintainable.

The main repo will stay as it is, while on the second one we want to add the main repo as a remote origin.

To do that let's first:

1. Create a new repo at github
2. Clone the main repo locally if not done already

You can then add the main repo as a remote origin:

3. `git remote rename origin upstream`
4. `git remote add origin URL_TO_MAIN_GITHUB_REPO`
5. `git push origin master`

Now you can work with it just like any other github repo.

To pull in patches from upstream, simply run `git pull upstream master && git push origin master`.

To underline I would follow this solution if you have two different projects based on some common changes, as branches works well for features / patches you would then want to merge to master once they are completed.

If, on the other hand, you simply have the same project with different features, then @Deniz da King solution is great.

Comment: okay it sounds very reasonable... what I wanted to is... I would like to git pull origin main into web server,  not local server.  I do jobs on local server and push them to branch, and then pull the branch to web server.

Comment: You will need to set the new repo instead of the main one on the related web server and from there you use git pull same way as you would with the main

Comment: For your question regarding `git pull` vs `git checkout`, short answer is use `git pull`. `git checkout` will pull the latest changes you have on a specific branch which you wouldn't really need if you keep separate projects as shown above